# Don't return same type from filter for efficiency

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let's say I have a `Map` in scala.

`Map.filter` returns a `Map`.
That means that it has to create a Map containing all the remaining items after the filter.

Since creating a map is not cheap in general (approximately O(nlog(n))), this is wasteful if all I want to do is iterate over the filtered results.

For example:

```scala
val map = Map(1 -> "hello", 50 -> "world", 100 -> "hi", 1000 -> "bye")
val filtered = map.filter(x => x._1 < 100)
for(x <- filtered) println(x._2)
```

I don't think using `map.toIterable` helps since the underlying is still a `Map`, and `filter` is virtual.

I don't know whether `map.view` has the required behavior or not.

I think `map.iterator` would work, but that means I can't iterate over the iterator twice. I suppose I could use `map.iterator.filter(x => x._1 < 100).toList`?

I could do `map.map(x => (x))`, but that means iterating over the Map twice.

What's the simplest, most idiomatic, not unnecessarily inefficient way of doing what I want?

Comment: If you want to iterate twice and you aren't going to build something too expensive from it, `view` is probably the best solution. If the `filter` is expensive or you are going to build something expensive from it, `iterator` would be the best.

Comment: Also, other option could be to write your own method that builds a **List** _(or any other structure you prefer)_ from the **Map** and the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if all you want to do is iterate in a for-comprehension or similar (i.e. `flatMap`, `foreach`, `map`), an intermediate collection isn't created:

```
for (x <- map if (x._1 < 100)) println(x._2)  // Doesn't create an intermediate Map
```

This desugars to

```
map.withFilter(x => x._1 < 100).foreach(x => println(x))
```

and `withFilter` is non-strict.

Answer (score 1):

Use `collect`.

```
val map = Map(1 -> "hello", 50 -> "world", 100 -> "hi", 1000 -> "bye")
val filtered : Iterable[String] = map.collect{
 case(x,y) if x<100 => y
}
```

Gives you only the values for which the key satisfies the condition